# Interface like behavior with django models - Overriding models.Field

Tags: django, interface, abstract

I am trying to design an abstract model that contains a field. Subclassed models will have this field, but they will be of various field types.

Example

```
class AbsModel(models.Model):
    data = models.??? #I want subclasses to choose this

    def __unicode__(self):
        return data.__str__()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TimeModel(AbsModel):
    data = models.TimeField()
    ...

class CharModel(AbsModel):
    data = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

I am looking for a way to enforce the existence of the data field so I can write **unicode** once for all objects.

If this isn't possible, how can I refer to the "data" field of the subclass when calling the super class's **unicode**

I have a feeling this second question has an obvious answer I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to override a superclass field where the field is of type models.Field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

You can get round this by defining a field of another type in the superclass, and then overriding it in the child (perhaps include a `__str__()` method just in case the data field isn't overriden).

```
from django.db import models


class AbsDataField:
    def __str__(self):
        return "undefined"

class AbsModel(models.Model):
    data = AbsDataField

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.data.__str__()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TimeModel(AbsModel):
    data = models.TimeField()
    #...

class CharModel(AbsModel):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that:

```
class AbsModel(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        if hasattr(self, "data") and isinstance(self.data, models.Field):
            return data.__str__()
        return u"Unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot do that in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted):

> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child
>   class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this
>   is not permitted for attributes that are `Field` instances (at least,
>   not at the moment). If a base class has a field called author, you
>   cannot create another model field called author in any class that
>   inherits from that base class.
>
> Overriding fields in a parent model leads to difficulties in areas
>   such as initializing new instances (specifying which field is being
>   initialized in `Model.__init__`) and serialization. These are features
>   which normal Python class inheritance doesn't have to deal with in
>   quite the same way, so the difference between Django model inheritance
>   and Python class inheritance isn't arbitrary.
>
> [...]
>
> Django will raise a `FieldError` if you override any model field in any
>   ancestor model.